# Creating/Returning Object Type Interface

Tags: java, object, interface

I am quite confused with the following when I was learning Data Structures in Java. Please look at the following code:

```
public interface Position<E> { 
   E getElement();
}

public interface PositionalList<E>{
   Position<E> first();
}
```

I am confused to how can the first method return the Position object which is an interface? Would appreciate an explanation which is easy to understand for a beginner. Thanks

Comment: It's not clear what you're confused about. Why shouldn't a method be able to return an interface?

Comment: well, so far I've only seen interface methods return int, string, char etc etc. 
I have never seen a method return an interface. I'm just asking cause this is new to me. Thanks for the link